# Kohler Push Button Diverter Leaking from Shower

Tags: shower

My plumber just installed the fixtures in my shower/tub and the shower stays running when the tub spout is running. I can tell he didn't even test it because when I turned on the water, I could hear the air getting flushed out. Even with the tub spout running at a low flow, the shower still leaks. All parts are brand new and I highly doubt the diverter is defective. Any feedback or tips would be appreciated. I called the plumber but he hasn't gotten back to me yet.

Here's a photo before tiling. Any ideas here? I'm fearful that we'll have to cut the drywall on the other side to fix this...
[image: Close-up view of valve]

[image: Wider view of valve]

[image: View of shower connection]

Comment: Post the links for the other photos in a comment,  somebody will edit them into the question.

Comment: Is the diverter all the way open?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So it looks like it was a bad part, see the o-ring missing below. BTW, you just need a deep socket wrench to remove the diverter, I wasted a few hours looking for plumber's wrenches before figuring this out...lol.

Glad it's working now but this valve kit was brand new, seems odd that something so critical would be missing. Also the part that I pulled seems used or refurbished (see discoloration). I hope the rest of the valve is ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the plumber didn't check for leaks he probably didn't let the water flush-out any pipe debris or other particles from the supply lines. Check for obstructions at the valve body. Also check the diverter for proper function with the valve fully opened. The more water pressure the tighter the seal.

Comment: not sure how to to flush out an obstruction at the supply line with all the tile up, but I can take the valve trim off.

Comment: My plumber said they did test it and did flush it out so not sure why it would just stop working. He said maybe need to take the cartridge out. I'll see if I can do that today.

Comment: your question states that when you opened the valve air came out so the plumber obviously hadn't checked for leaks. The valve can be unscrewed to check the hot and cold ports for debris. Shut the main off before disassembling the valve.

Answer (score 0):

1: It's called brand-new-broken. Get on the horn with the manufacturer of the valve.

2: If it was the plumber's fault, they melted a seal or something while soldering.

After being advised by both of these parties, you'll know better about who gets to pay to fix it. If it's #1, you might have to eat the labor on it yourself, less the cost of the new valve, plus *you* get to re-tile. If it's #2, you have to "play nice" or call lawyers.

Comment: Plumber said I need a new cartridge, I called Kohler and they said I need a new Diverter Valve. they sent one out for no charge. I'll install tomorrow and see how it goes.